# multiple partial views and one submit button in a layout view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview, model-validation

Im not sure if this is the right approach to do this. In my searchs only found multiple partial views and one submit button but  not in a layout.

I have tree different views each with their own model with the same _ViewStart.cshtml -> _Layout.cshtml (MVC convention). This is the control for the first one:

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult UpDateData1 ()
    {
        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpDateData1(Data1Model model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SOME CODE…

        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError…
        }
        return View(model);
```

The 3 views are pretty generics, but I don't want a submit button in there.

Also in  _Layout.cshtml I have a  partial view with common validation code for  the 3 views:

```
<section id="main">
        @RenderBody()
        <div>
            @Html.Partial("_CommonValidation ", new store.Models.CommonValidation())
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Only one Button" />
        </div>
        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("BackTo…", "MyAccountConfig", "Account")
        </div>
    </section>
```

I don’t want a submit button in _CommonValidation view neither.

It is possible to use "ONLY ONE BUTTON”  submit button in the Layout.cshtml to validate the models of the partial _CommonValidation and the RenderBody() views ? it is a good practice to include strongly typed partial views in the _Layout.cshtml view?  I'm new to MVC 3 so I don’t have any idea what direction to take… JavaScripts, HTML Helpers maybe...
Thanks